# Excel & VBA: Skip calculating formula in Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a rather simple issue with Macro. In it, I assign a formula to a cell. I would like it not to calculate it at first and do calculation only after some other part of Macro is finished. I thought I would do something like this:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Cells(StartRow, 4 + i).Formula = "FORMULA"
...
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

But that doesn't work. It stops automatic calculations, but not for that cell - it still performs the calculation right after I assign the formula. Is there a way to skip it?

To clarify the exact prupose of this: in my actual code I'm assigning a formula to a group of cells in a cycle. Everytime I assign it to one cell - it calculates it. I figured if I will first assign them all and then do the calculation - it would be faster. As a matter of fact **it is**. So instead of assigning it in a cycle, I assign it to the first cell and then do autofill. Autofilled formulas wait until I enable automatic calculation and I get a much faster macro. However, the initial assignemnt is still calculated which makes macro almost twice as slow.

Comment: just a thought to try: can you keep the formula in some hidden cell - and in your macro only PasteSpecial the formula? With a bit of luck that works similar to the autofill and only calculates at the end...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. place the formula in the cell with a prefix character
2. continue the macro
3. "activate" the formula

for example:

```
Sub dural()
    With Range("A1")
        .Value = "'=1+2"
        MsgBox " "
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why .Value will get rid of the ' prefix?

Answer (score 3):

@Alex, you can delay the calculation as @Gary answer. However, you was asking the question because you need **"SPEED to CYCLE through cells"** while assign a formula, right?

If yes, from my point of view, if you are *NOT* using the formulas until *ALL* the formulas are assigned in the excel sheet, you will gain a **lot of speed** by writing all the formulas at once using an array (a single step in VBA).

The procedure is: first put all the formulas to an VBA array of strings, and later on to use for example `Range("B1:B100").Formula = ArrayWithFormulas`. In that example you are assigning 100 formulas at once, without recalculation in between.

You will see a large improve in SPEED if use an array to write all the cells at ones instead of writing cell by cell! (Don't loop using `cells(r,c+i)` if you have a lot of cells to go through). Here one example:

```
Sub CreateBunchOfFormulas()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim ARRAY_OF_FORMULAS() As Variant 'Note: Don't replace Variant by String!
  ReDim ARRAY_OF_FORMULAS(1 To 100, 1 To 1) 
                          ' For Vertical use: (1 to NumRows,1 to 1)
                          ' for Horizontal:   (1 to 1,1 to NumCols)
                          ' for 2D use:  (1 to NumRows,1 to NumCols)
  'Create the formulas...
  For i = 1 To 100
     ARRAY_OF_FORMULAS(i, 1) = "=1+3+" & i ' Or any other formula...
  Next i

  ' <-- your extra code here...
  '      (New formulas won't be calculated. They are not in the Excel sheet yet!
  '       If you want that no other old formula to recalculate use the old trick:
  '      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual )

  'At the very end, write the formulas in the excel at once...
  Range("B1:B100").Formula = ARRAY_OF_FORMULAS

End Sub
```

If you want an extra delay in the new formula, then you can use @Gary trick, but applied to a range, not to a single cell. For that start the formulas with a `'` like `'=1+2` and add the following code at the end:

```
  '... previous code, but now formulas starting with (')
  Range("B1:B100").Formula = ARRAY_OF_FORMULAS   
  'Formulas not calculated yet, until next line is executed
  Range("B1:B100").Value  = Range("B1:B100").Value ' <~~ @Gary's trick
End Sub
```

Last, a small snipped: if your formulas are in a horizontal arrangement (Means one formula for column A, other for column B, etc) and just a small number of columns, then you can keep in mind the a shorter version of previous code:

```
Dim a as Variant 'Note that no () needed
a = Array("=1+3","=4+8","=5*A1","=sum(A1:C1)")
Range("A1:D1").Formula = ARRAY_OF_FORMULA    ' Just a single row
' or...
Range("A1:D100").Formula = ARRAY_OF_FORMULA  ' If you want to repeat formulas
                                             ' in several rows.
```

Finally, You can use the method `.FormulaR1C1` instead of `.Formula` in all the previous code examples, if you want an easy way to use relative references in your formula...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sounds interesting. Thanks! So far I've used Gary's suggestion pretty successfully. I add formulas with apostrophe in a cycle to the entire range and then run them all with Range(whatever).Value = Range(whatever).Value

Comment: Good! If you see you need to improve the speed, you can use this ;-) . More tips about the speed, here: [(1) Excel VBA : Efficiency and Performance](http://www.avdf.com/apr98/art_ot003.html) - [(2) Fast coding](http://blogs.msdn.com/excel/archive/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices.aspx) - [(3) Microsoft info about passing an array to VB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153090/en-us)